# How to change Laravel 5 sessions to redis

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis

I now set a lot of values to the session using `Session::put` and `Session::get`. If I want to use Redis throughout the application, is it true that I just need to replace all `Session::` with `Redis::` to make it work?

By the way, I already installed the Redis package

Comment: Set the env configuration `SESSION_DRIVER` to `redis` in .env or as an actual environment variable. Or in config/session.php change the driver to redis

Comment: See https://laravel.com/docs/master/session#configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is just changing your `.env` file :

`SESSION_DRIVER=redis`

and use `Session::get()` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You should change in connfig/session.php `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),` file to redis.